# Create and add a view as a subview through code

Tags: ios, ios6

i have a view "MyView1".

I want to create and add a view "MyView2" that has a textfield and a button as a subview but through code. Can anyone please help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `[myView1 addSubview:myView2];`

The following can be helpful as well.

```
[myView1 insertSubview:<#(UIView *)#> aboveSubview:<#(UIView *)#>];
[myView1 insertSubview:<#(UIView *)#> atIndex:<#(NSInteger)#>];
[myView1 insertSubview:<#(UIView *)#> belowSubview:<#(UIView *)#>];
```